# Как получать HWND_BROADCAST сообщения без создания дополнительного UI?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, vb.net

Сторонний процесс посылает сообщения `UWM_HELLO`.

Для этого используется [RegisterWindowMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagea) и [SendNotifyMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendnotifymessagea).

Предполагаю, что делается как-то так:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string message);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool SendNotifyMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private uint UWM_HELLO;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        UWM_HELLO = RegisterWindowMessage("TEST MESSAGE");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendNotifyMessage(new IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), UWM_HELLO, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Подскажите легковесный способ, что бы получать сообщение `UWM_HELLO` в своём коде. Т.е. чтобы не требовалось создавать форму, а потом её скрывать.

UPD. Я имел в виду, чтобы не требовалось создавать визуальный компонент, с которым мог взаимодействовать пользователь.

Comment: *Потом скрывать* -А почему нельзя сразу скрытую создать? Просто передавать параметры в CreateWindow без WS_VISIBLE

Comment: Окно - это необязательно прям "_визуальный компонент, с которым мог взаимодействовать пользователь_". Окно может быть невидимым и/или иметь нулевой размер. Окно это прежде всего базовый объект механизма сообщений, визуальная составляющая там необязательна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перехватывать сообщения, посланные с `HWND_BROADCAST`, можно при помощи [NativeWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow). При этом не будут создаваться ни какие формы или визуальные компоненты, с которыми мог бы взаимодействовать пользователь.

Для примера можно глянуть, как это реализовано в самом Framework, а именно [TimerNativeWindow](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Timer.cs,7681525c85c5d4bc) (спасибо [bcwhims](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41173013/1133809)).

Таким образом, создаем свою реализацию:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Runtime.Versioning;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
        public class MyNativeWindow : NativeWindow
        {
            private const int WmClose = 0x0010;

            [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2006:UseSafeHandleToEncapsulateNativeResources")]
            private static readonly HandleRef HwndMessage = new HandleRef(null, new IntPtr(-3));

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
            private static extern IntPtr PostMessage(HandleRef hwnd, int msg, int wparam, int lparam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Process)]
            private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(HandleRef hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Process)]
            private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            private static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string message);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

            private readonly uint UWM_HELLO;
            private readonly Action Action;

            public MyNativeWindow(Action action)
            {
                Action = action;
                UWM_HELLO = RegisterWindowMessage("TEST MESSAGE");
            }

            public bool CreateWindow()
            {
                if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    var cp = new CreateParams
                    {
                        //Style = 0,
                        //ExStyle = 0,
                        //ClassStyle = 0,
                        Caption = this.GetType().FullName,
                        // Parent = (IntPtr)HwndMessage
                    };

                    //if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
                    //{
                    //    cp.Parent = (IntPtr)HwndMessage;
                    //}

                    CreateHandle(cp);
                }
                return Handle != IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            public void DestroyWindow()
            {
                DestroyWindow(true, IntPtr.Zero);
            }

            private bool GetInvokeRequired(IntPtr hWnd)
            {
                if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                int pid;
                var hwndThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(new HandleRef(this, hWnd), out pid);
                var currentThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
                return (hwndThread != currentThread);
            }

            private void DestroyWindow(bool destroyHwnd, IntPtr hWnd)
            {
                if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    hWnd = Handle;
                }

                if (GetInvokeRequired(hWnd))
                {
                    PostMessage(new HandleRef(this, hWnd), WmClose, 0, 0);
                    return;
                }

                lock (this)
                {
                    if (destroyHwnd)
                    {
                        base.DestroyHandle();
                    }
                }
            }

            public override void DestroyHandle()
            {
                DestroyWindow(false, IntPtr.Zero);
                base.DestroyHandle();
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                if(m.Msg == UWM_HELLO)
                {
                    Action?.Invoke();
                    return;
                }

                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
        }
    }
```

Чтоб заработало нужно создать экземпляр `MyNativeWindow` и вызвать метод `CreateWindow`:

```cs
    this.nativeWindow = new MyNativeWindow(
        ()=>
        {
            WriteHelloNW();
        }
    );
    this.nativeWindow.CreateWindow();
```

При завершении работы вызываем метод `DestroyWindow`:

```
this.nativeWindow.DestroyWindow();
```

Вот пример. Для пущей наглядности запустим обработчик в отдельном STA потоке, чтоб тормоза основного UI потока не мешали обрабатывать сообщения:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
        class SecondWindowsThread : IDisposable
        {
            private SynchronizationContext ctx;
            private MyNativeWindow testWindow;

            public SecondWindowsThread(Action action)
            {
                ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                try
                {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(
                        () =>
                        {
                            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                            this.ctx = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();
                            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(this.ctx);
                            mre.Set();
                            Application.Run();
                        }
                    );
                    thread.IsBackground = true;
                    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    thread.Start();
                    mre.WaitOne();

                    this.ctx.Send(
                        (o) =>
                        {
                            this.testWindow = new MyNativeWindow(action);
                            this.testWindow.CreateWindow();
                        },
                        null);
                }
                finally
                {
                    mre.Dispose();
                }
            }

            #region IDisposable Support
            private bool disposedValue = false;

            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (disposedValue) return;

                if (this.ctx != null)
                {
                    this.ctx.Send(
                        (_) =>
                        {
                            this.testWindow?.DestroyWindow();
                            Application.ExitThread();
                        },
                        null);
                    this.ctx = null;
                }
                disposedValue = true;
            }

            #endregion

            public SynchronizationContext SynchronizationContext
            {
                get
                {
                    if (this.disposedValue) throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(SynchronizationContext));
                    return this.ctx;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Можно посмотреть [лабораторную](https://github.com/maliutin/lab-send-wm-to-another-process).

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто задумайтесь что значит WND в `HWND_BROADCAST`. Легко догадаться, что это от слова "window". А MSDN нам подробно объясняет:

> If this parameter is HWND_BROADCAST, the message is sent to all
>   top-level windows in the system, including disabled or invisible
>   unowned windows, overlapped windows, and pop-up windows; but the
>   message is not sent to child windows.

Оконные сообщения посылаются **окнам**! Ваш вопрос "*как получить оконное сообщение не создавая окна*" просто не имеет смысла. Нет окна - нет сообщения, точка.

Comment: Можно общесистемный хук попробовать приделать, но инфы будет много..

Comment: @NewView, ТС хочет что-то более простое, чем создание невидимого окна. Общесистемный хук в эту категорию вряд ли попадает.

Comment: Я это как возможное развитие мысли ТС, как реализовать, информация к размышлению.. :)

Comment: `window` ресурс, которым оперирует система и он может быть не только визуальным компонентом. Я упомянул формы как визуальный компонент, который часто используют для перехвата сообщений.